# Check for duplicates when saving

Tags: nhibernate, duplicates, unique

How to check for duplicates when saving new object?

Scenario:

- check for duplicates by some query -> when no duplicates perform saving

Is not good because between ***check*** and ***save*** there is plenty of time when other user can insert new object with the same data (high activity of users).

Should I check for exception when saving or what?

Comment: Try the optimistic-lock attribute that's at the class and property levels. I'm not sure it affects inserts though.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
{
    bool alreadyExists = session.Query<MyEntity>()
                                .Any(x => x.UniqueProp = newEntity.UniqueProp);
    if (!alreadyExists)
        session.Save(newEntity)
    tx.Commit();
}
```

The `Serializable` isolation level guarantees nobody can insert a matching row between the query and the insert. Of course the downside is reduced concurrency because of the range locks.

Handling the exception is an alternative.

Comment: "high activity of users" disqualify this solution. :(

Comment: @dario-g: No, it doesn't. It's only a problem if collisions are frequent. It depends on the DB, but SQL Server for example uses range locks, not table locks for Serializable (make sure you have appropriate indexes)

Comment: Yeap - in theory but in practice is different - application slows down :(

Comment: @dario-g: have you tried? The only alternative is catching and decoding the exception.